# Slided down <ul> automatically toggling up when page is scrolled down in Chrome browser in mobile phones

Tags: jquery

I have a responsive navigation in my website. I used jQuery `slideToggle()` for toggling the navigation in mobile phones. Everything works properly except one. The error is showing only in Chrome browser for Android (I checked all the other browsers including Chrome in iOS). The problem is, after we toggled down the navigation and while we are scrolling down to see the full navigation the navigation is automatically sliding up. I used the following code for toggling the navigation.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobmenu', function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 991) {
        $('.leftmenu > ul').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the error? Would it not be better to use CSS media queries to tailor the view for mobile devices?

Comment: But I need to toggle the navigation on clicking a button.

Comment: you may have the click event bind to the `.leftmenu` as well or `.mobmeniu` is over `.leftmeniu` thus registering the scroll as a click

Comment: Actually the click event is binding '.mobmenu' only. And `.leftmenu` is not even a child of `.mobmenu`. They are just siblings. If you are true, then why this error only showing in Chrome browser for android?

Comment: provide your html code please

Comment: `<ul class="leftmenu">`   
`<li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>`  
`<li><a href="aboutus.php">about us</a></li>`                      
`<li><a href="contactus.php">contact us</a></li>`  
`</ul>`    
`<span class="mobmenu">  
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>  
</span>`